# Networkx node reachability - if condition

Tags: python, networkx, gurobi

I am trying to implement a basic version of the set covering problem in Python. My binary decision variable whether to locate a facility at a node or not is `x[j]`. I am struggling with a constraint that one node `i` can only cover another node `j` if the weight of the edges between the two nodes is smaller than 4000.

The constraint that I have implemented is

```
#add constraint
for i in G.nodes():
    model.addConstr(sum(a[i,j]*x[j] >= 1 for j in G.nodes))
```

but I do not know how to define that `a(i,j) == 1` only if the distance between the nodes is "coverable".

I have tried defining something like this before defining the model and using it as a parameter, but it does not work...

```
for i,j in G.nodes():
    if(nx.shortest_path_length(G,i,j) <= 4000):
        return a[i,j] == 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please elaborate on how the shortest_path_length code section does not work? Also, which networkx class is your graph? Would it be able to include a small set of data that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. My graph is a directed graph that I constructed using a numpy distance matrix. ```G = from_numpy_matrix(distance_matrix, create_using = nx.DiGraph)``` The distance matrix was calculated by using the road distances between coordinates... Unfortunately, I cannot include the coordinates here. 

The solution that I tried with shortest paths does not work as it states a is not defined and that return cannot be used within a function

Comment: How about modifying the `distance_matrix`, e.g. `distance_matrix[distance_matrix>4000]=0`, so that you simply remove those links from your graph?
Otherwise we would need a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with dummy nodes/distances/coordinates